# What's wrong in my TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, compilation-error

When I try to generate a PDF, my program give me errors.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines=middle,
xlabel=$X$,
ylabel=$Y$,
domain=2.25:5.75,
xmin=2.25,
xmax=5.75,
ymin=-1.5,
ymax=1.5,
samples=1000,
xticklabels={,,},
yticklabels={,,},
extra x ticks={3.5,4,4.5},
extra x tick labels={$x_0-\delta$,$x_0$,$x_0+\delta$},
ytick style={draw=none},
xtick style={draw=none},
extra x tick style={ticklabel pos=top},
extra y ticks={-0.85790625,-1.001,−1.14409375},
extra y tick labels={$L-\varepsilon$,$L$,$L+\varepsilon$}]
\addplot[blue]{(x^5-2*x^4-24*x^3+x^2+x-7)/1000};
\draw[dashed] (3.5,0) -- (3.5,-0.85790625);
\draw[dashed] (0,-0.85790625) -- (3.5,-0.85790625);
\draw[dashed] (4,0) -- (4,-1.001);
\draw[dashed] (0,-1.001) -- (4,-1.001);
\draw[dashed] (4.5,0) -- (4.5,−1.14409375);
\draw[dashed] (0,−1.14409375) -- (4.5,−1.14409375);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: would you like to add the preamble to the code for a proper study

Answer (score 6):

Since you already have some reputation you should know, that it would be nice to have a [minimal (not) working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), because sometimes the root cause of an error can be found in the preamble (or somewhere else). Besides that we -- the helpers -- than can immediately start with solving the problem instead of first guessing the missing parts ourselves.

When you have that here is how you (in future) can find out yourself where the problem originates from.

- Create a copy of your project (so you still have the original).
- Start deleting everything that you are pretty sure has nothing to do with the error (i.e. when you are in a book and the compiler comes to e.g. chapter 3 it should be very safe to remove chapters 1 and 2). The same error should still raise when you compile again.
- From the LOG file you should be able to ruffly say where the error is raised. Delete everything that for sure is after that part.
- Now start narrowing down error by commenting about half of the remaining text. If the same error still is raised then it is sure to delete the commented part. If the error is gone than the error is in the commented part and it is pretty sure that the uncommented part can be deleted.
- Repeat the previous step over and over again. In between you can also start removing stuff from preamble that isn't needed any more.
- Most often then a quite small amount of code remains were the error is still raised.
- Either you are then able to find it yourself and can fix it, or, if not, of course you are free to ask for help e.g. here at TeX.SX.

I could narrow down the error to the following code. Uncommenting one of the lines raises the error you also got, right? Remember what the error is complaining about and have a look at the commented lines. Do you see a pattern?

```
% used PGFPlots v1.17
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
%        extra y ticks={−1.14409375},
    ]
        % (sometimes) at least one `\addplot` command is needed to execute all `axis` options
        \addplot coordinates {(-1,-1)};
%        \draw (0,−1.14409375) -- (4.5,−1.14409375);
%        \draw (4.5,−1.14409375);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ok, the error is raised from `−1.14409375`.

(Continue with only uncommenting the `extra y ticks` line.)

- Now you could either track down the error even more or first make it work, e.g. try another number like `0`. This will work.
- Tracking down the error even more would result in `−1` which still raises the error.
- Changing the number to e.g. `−2` does still raise the error.
- Removing the `−` will work.
- (Again) adding a minus sign and will work too !!!

So the `−` is the real root cause of the problem.

So this sign does not seem to be a [hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), but some other character that looks very similar to that. Maybe it is a real [minus sign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#), maybe a [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash). (We could try to find out what it really is, but I think that is not of interest here.)

So my guess is that you have copied the number from somewhere instead of typing it yourself, right?

Comment: Very nice tutorial as an example on how-to MWE, should be saved! (BTW, `vim` say the culprit is `<−> 8722, U+2212 MINUS SIGN, ^K-2, &minus;`)

Comment: @Rmano, thanks for the flowers.