# Dimension too large for this tikz. How to resolve?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am using MATLAB to plot some graphs and then using `matlab2tikz()` to convert these MATLAB graphs to tikz. The issue I have now is that one of the graphs I have after converting it to tikz, failed to compile with an error of dimension too large. I was wondering what are some ways to resolve this issue. I present my graph in MATLAB. Unfortunately Tex stack exchange does not allow me to post more than 30000 characters thus I can not upload my lengthy code.

[image]

If fixing this issue is not possible, then I would hope for someone to plot this graph for me if possible with the legends and I would be extremely thankful.

---

**Update**: I think it would be better to show the domain that perhaps is causing this error:

```
width=4.521in,
height=3.566in,
at={(0.758in,0.481in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-60,
xmax=60,
xlabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
xlabel={f (Hz)},
ymin=-9e-06,
ymax=9e-06,
ylabel style={font=\color{white!15!black}},
ylabel={X, H in uHz},
axis background/.style={fill=white},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
```

---

**Update 2**: It is not actually seen in graph because I cropped too much but at the top of the y-axis it was displaying 8x10^-6.

---

**Update 3**: To further clarify more about this graph, I wanted the graph of this signal to be zoomed in fraction of micro-hertz. This was done by using two MATLAB commands:

```
ylim([0 1E-6])  %Displays y-axis in order of 10^-6
set(gca, 'YLim',[-9E-6  9e-6])   %graphs from -9x10^-6 to 9x10^-6
```

---

**Update 4**: I have pasted my code on Overleaf and these are the exact error I recieved:

```
Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log.
 main.tex, line 2226
Dimension too large.

<recently read> \pgf@yy 
                        
l.2226 \end{axis}
                 
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

 main.tex, line 2226
Dimension too large.

\pgfusepath ...@y by.5\pgflinewidth \ifdim \pgf@y 
                                                  >\pgf@picmaxy \global \pgf...
l.2226 \end{axis}
                 
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

 main.tex, line 2226
Dimension too large.

\pgf@transformcm ...\pgf@x \global \pgf@y =\pgf@y 
                                                  \xdef \pgf@tempaa {\pgf@sy...
l.2226 \end{axis}
                 
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

 main.tex, line 2226
Dimension too large.

<argument> \pgf@y 
                  
l.2226 \end{axis}
                 
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

 main.tex, line 2226
Dimension too large.

<recently read> \pgf@y 
                       
l.2226 \end{axis}
                 
I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.

 main.tex, line 2226
Dimension too large.

<argument> \pgf@y 
                  
l.2226 \end{axis}
                 
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 26385 strings out of 480906
 656043 string characters out of 5908280
 1585782 words of memory out of 5000000
 41557 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 535088 words of font info for 29 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 74i,9n,127p,718b,1842s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

---

**Final Update**: Here is the link to the tikz code (without main document and packages):

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QarQN-31eMwIvIx67GbW5YQOoq0tkN5G3ptctUYgu1o/edit?usp=sharing

---

---

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) From the given code it is still (I think) impossible to help you, because you haven't provided any data regarding the plot itself, i.e. the function or data table you are trying to plot. Could you edit your question again and add some details on that point?

Comment: Is it possible to post a link for the code instead of pasting it here because it is too long or can I post the first half in the question and the second half in the answer section? @StefanPinnow

Comment: A link is suboptimal, because it can't be valid any more in the future and thus, later others can't replicate the problem any more. From your comment I think you don't try to plot the *function* but have a data table/file. If that is too large, try to reduce it by e.g. reducing it to only every *x*'s point. This should be simple to achieve in Matlab directly.

Comment: Like @StefanPinnow I do not think it is useful to post links. The pgfmanual 3.1.8 suggests on p. 640 to use `/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal}`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Hello, no I have not tried that but what does it do specifically and where do I use it? @user241086

Comment: I don't know since I do not follow external links. You can try to add it to the `tikzpicture` environment that contains the axis. `\begin{tikzpicture}[/pgf/fpu/install only={reciprocal}]`. A cleaner way would be if you cook down your example to a short code that has the problem. This is a bit cumbersome but makes it much more likely to get a real answer.

Comment: Alright thank you very much! I shall apply it now

Comment: I have applied it but it seems that the error is still focused on the dimensionality. Furthermore, I will take your suggestion and try to rephrase my question properly. Thank you! @user241086

Comment: If your code still is too long, please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/585126/95441 where I roughly described how you can narrow down the root cause of a problem/error. From that -- together with reducing the samples or your data file -- you should be able to show us a not working minimal example which still shows the error.

Comment: @user241086 Do you have a formula (or other description) for the red curve? Instead of ploting graphs in Mathlab, then convert to tikz code, it is better to plot directly in TikZ, or Asymptote

Comment: You have over 40 pages of data points. With an xmin to xmax of -60 to 60 and step size about .1 you have about 1200 points for each plot. That's too much: 200 is more reasonable. Try eliminating points where the x value is not close to an integer. That would give about 120 points per plot. As user 241086 suggests it's probably better to plot directly in Tikz.